# Can't get unoconv to work without X

Tags: linux, unoconv

I'm trying to convert a Word document to plain text, and get this error:

```
user@server$ unoconv --format=txt test.docx 
/usr/lib64/libreoffice/program/soffice.bin X11 error: Can't open display: 
    Set DISPLAY environment variable, use -display option
    or check permissions of your X-Server
    (See "man X" resp. "man xhost" for details)
Error: Unable to connect or start own listener. Aborting.
```

The version of libreoffice on this server is LibreOffice 4.3.7.2 430(Build:2) and it's running CentOS 7.

So I installed Debian 8.3.0 in VirtualBox on my own computer (since I don't have root privileges on the CentOS machine), and with it came LibreOffice 4.3.3.2 430m0(Build:2). To my surprise converting the MS Word file worked when I tried it through SSH, and X wasn't running at all.

Does anyone have an idea of how I can make it work on CentOS? Is an update of libreoffice required (even though it's never than the version I have on the Debian machine)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out libreoffice-headless was required. I installed it using yum.